# Include WPS in Geoserver (Build with Eclipse)

Tags: geoserver

I'm running GeoServer from Eclipse.
Now I want to create my own WPS. How can I implement it in my Eclipse-Project?
I created the *.class-File and don't know, where to put it.

Normally, when I'm using the "normal" GeoServer-Installation, I have to put the *.jar-File in the WEB-INF/lib directory.